# (MySQL 5.7) How to combine my two queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

How can I combine my two queries in MySQL 5.7:

(windows functions doesn't work)

1: This query is finding all dialogues where more than 10 messages and spaced at least an hour apart.

```
SELECT `dialog_id`
  FROM `messages`
  GROUP BY `dialog_id`
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10 
    AND MIN(`timestamp`) + INTERVAL 1 HOUR < MAX(`timestamp`)
```

2: The second query selects two last rows for each dialogue.

```
SELECT * FROM messages tbl WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages tbl1 WHERE tbl1.dialog_id = tbl.dialog_id AND tbl1.id >= tbl.id AND 
(user_from = :user_from OR user_to = :user_to)) <= 2 ORDER BY dialog_id DESC
```

So, what I want is to select last two rows for each dialogue that lasted more than an hour *and* where more than 10 messages were sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I didn't got you properly is this what you are looking for:

```
    SELECT * FROM messages tbl WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages tbl1 WHERE tbl1.dialog_id = tbl.dialog_id AND tbl1.id >= tbl.id AND 
(user_from = :user_from OR user_to = :user_to)) <= 2
and dialog_id in (SELECT `dialog_id`
  FROM `messages`
  GROUP BY `dialog_id`
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10 
    AND MIN(`timestamp`) + INTERVAL 1 HOUR < MAX(`timestamp`))

 ORDER BY dialog_id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i got a error:
 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where dialog_id in (SELECT `dialog_id`
  FROM `messages`
  GROUP BY `dialog_id`
  HAVING COUNT(*)' at line 3

Comment: Would you please share table structures along with some sample data.

Comment: @JohnDoe I have changed my answer. Please try and let me know your feedback. Currently I am not in a position to check in mysql db.

Comment: Oh, you did magic! it's work fine now! Thank you a lot, Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can accomplish this with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages tbl
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
     messages tbl1
     tbl1.dialog_id = tbl.dialog_id
     tbl1.id >= tbl.id
     (user_from = :user_from OR user_to = :user_to)) <= 2
  and dialog_id in (
    SELECT `dialog_id`
    FROM `messages`
    GROUP BY `dialog_id`
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
       AND MIN(`timestamp`) + INTERVAL 1 HOUR < MAX(`timestamp`))
ORDER BY dialog_id DESC
```

You might have to adjust it slightly, since I don't have the full structure of your tables, but the principle would go as follows: get all the dialogue_ids matching your 10 and over an hour criteria, then use it to limit the messages returned from your "Get the most recent two" logic.

Comment: Aeron, thank you for answer and for editing my post. but i got same error. 

Thank you for your answer but i got a error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where dialog_id in (SELECT dialog_id FROM messages GROUP BY dialog_id HAVING COUNT(*)' at line 3

Comment: Then the issue will likely be a bit more subtle than what I can assume without seeing your structure. Also: the error you show doesn't appear in any of the code I posted, so I am curious to know if you tried the code I posted, since it seems to come from the other posted answer :/

Comment: Yes, of course i'm tried, i just couldn't miss it. Anyway it's solved now. But thank you anyway